# Relevel command in R not "releveling"

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm using a form of the relevel command that seems to run without error, but it has not successfully releveled my baseline variable (I want my baseline to be "manage") when I go to run my model again.

mods= ~ relevel(factor(ENROLLMENT_PLAN, ref="manage"))

model4 <- lm(formula= Y ~ ENROLLMENT_PLAN + X + X, data=mydata);
stargazer(model4, header=FALSE, font.size = "tiny", type = "text", align=TRUE, single.row = FALSE, column.sep.width = "1pt", digits=2)

Could someone please assist with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't change the `ENROLLMENT_PLAN` inside `mydata`. (What is `mods` BTW?)

```
mydata$ENROLLMENT_PLAN = relevel(factor(mydata$ENROLLMENT_PLAN), ref="manage")

model4 <- lm(formula= Y ~ ENROLLMENT_PLAN + X + X, data=mydata)
```

Comment: Thank you for the help (I just found someone using mods online, my mistake) - however, now I'm receiving this error: Error in factor(mydata$ENROLLMENT_PLAN, ref = "manage") : 
  unused argument (ref = "manage").

Comment: @razztazz Sorry, I misplaced the bracket. Fixed now!